# Which datatype choose?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If we have numbers like 25-135, 87-987, 25-135.115-15, 25-135-511 - which datatype is appropriate to use in the table? Please advise.

Comment: Brevity is always appreciate, but perhaps a little more context would help here

Comment: Please clarify your question more. What is this string?

Comment: what do they represent?

Comment: It depends on what the numbers will be used for. If you can edit the question to tell us, we'll be able to help you more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a character based data type.  First they are not real numbers.  Second, although these contain numbers, you will never sum or average them.  They look like identifiers.  If they will not be aggregated, they should not be a number.

For example, you'll never try to find the average zip code for your customers.  That is because it is a character field that happens to consist of five numbers.

A counter argument is that numeric data types take up less space then character.  Although that is true, storage is cheap and my team spends far more money fixing data quality issues because the incorrect data type was used.

Answer (score 3):

Reading between the lines these sound like control codes (invoice numbers).  I always store invoice numbers as varchars because people want to put prefixes on them and the like and usually you don't need numeric range searches.